# In a tibble nesting tibbles (inside list-columns), how to update tibbles to rename columns with a common name?

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, purrr

Using `purrr`, I've summarized `iris` data into a new mutated list-column:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_tibble <-
  iris %>%
  nest(data = everything()) %>%
  mutate(summary_tbl = map(.x = data,
                           ~ .x %>%
                             group_by(Species) %>%
                             summarise(mean_by_cat = mean(Sepal.Length))))

my_tibble
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   data               summary_tbl     
#>   <list>             <list>          
#> 1 <tibble [150 x 5]> <tibble [3 x 2]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If we unnest `data` or `summary_tbl` we can see that both contain a tibble, with some overlapping column names (in this case `Species`):

```r
my_tibble %>%
  pull(data)

## [[1]]
## # A tibble: 150 x 5
##    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
##           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
##  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
##  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
##  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
##  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
##  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
##  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
##  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
##  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
##  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
## 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
## # ... with 140 more rows

my_tibble %>%
  pull(summary_tbl)

## [[1]]
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   Species    mean_by_cat
## * <fct>            <dbl>
## 1 setosa            5.01
## 2 versicolor        5.94
## 3 virginica         6.59
```

Is there an efficient way to rename a column name that appears inside *any* of `my_tibble`'s list-columns?
For example, if we define:

```r
var_to_rename <- "Species"
new_name <- "my_grouping_var"
```

Then provided with `my_tibble`, `var_to_rename`, and `new_name`, how can we programmatically get the following?

```r
my_tibble %>%
  pull(data)

## [[1]]
## # A tibble: 150 x 5
##    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width my_grouping_var
##           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
##  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
##  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
##  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
##  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
##  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
##  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
##  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
##  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
##  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
## 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
## # ... with 140 more rows

my_tibble %>%
  pull(summary_tbl)

## [[1]]
## # A tibble: 3 x 2
##   my_grouping_var  mean_by_cat
## * <fct>            <dbl>
## 1 setosa            5.01
## 2 versicolor        5.94
## 3 virginica         6.59
```

Clearly I could have renamed `Species` to `my_grouping_var` before the `mutate` part, but my question is aimed at renaming an existing tibble after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do :

```
library(dplyr)

my_tibble <- my_tibble %>%
                 mutate(across(.fns = ~.[[1]] %>% 
                     rename_with(~new_name, all_of(var_to_rename)) %>% list()))

my_tibble %>% pull(summary_tbl)

#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  my_grouping_var mean_by_cat
#* <fct>                 <dbl>
#1 setosa                 5.01
#2 versicolor             5.94
#3 virginica              6.59
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a function you can use `rename()` with the curly-curly operator (`{{}}`) and the colon-equal operator (`:=`):

```r
foo = function(var_to_rename, new_name){
  my_tibble %>% 
    mutate(summary_tbl = map(summary_tbl, ~{
      rename(.x, {{new_name}}:={{var_to_rename}})
    }))
}
my_tibble2=foo("Species", "my_grouping_var")

my_tibble2 %>%
  pull(summary_tbl)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   my_grouping_var mean_by_cat
#>   <fct>                 <dbl>
#> 1 setosa                 5.01
#> 2 versicolor             5.94
#> 3 virginica              6.59
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

More info on how to use `dplyr`'s tidy-evaluation in functions on https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html.